# log system DEBUG (7)

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml, log, system.log

My system log is creating massive amounts of DEBUG (7) log

it logs every layout xml from frontend and adminhtml

any suggestions how to stop/fix this?

Many Thanks

example

```
[...]
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog_msrp.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/payment.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cataloginventory.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/shipping.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/checkout.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bml.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/poll.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/review.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/tag.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/reports.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/wishlist.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypaluk.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/contacts.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/sendfriend.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/rss.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/productalert.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/oauth.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/authorizenet.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/centinel.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/configurableswatches.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/newsletter.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/pagecache.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/persistent.xml

[...]

DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/report.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customer.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/promo.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/adminnotification.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/dataflow.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/index.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/cms.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/search.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/tag.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/widget.xml
DEBUG (7): htdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/tax.xml
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is come code that is logging the layouts that are being called whenever a view is loaded.

Magento allows you to log data using the following:

> Mage::log('some data');

The above will result in `DEBUG (7): some data` in the system.log file

Perform a search for `Mage::log` on you `app > code > local` folder, find the line that is logging and remove/comment it out. If you can't find any instance, try the `community` folder.

If you come across no hits from above, try the `app > design` folder

Answer (score 0):

my problem was caused by this line

```
Mage::log(print_r($filename, true));
/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/
```

Many Thanks

Comment: So, looks like my answer was correct? Glad you found the problematic line